# android: Adding a Custom action button in the softkeybord

Tags: android, keyboard

i need to know to how add a new custom action button exactly at the lefthand corner of my soft keyboard...so once i tap on the ok(my custom button name), it should force the softkeyboard to hide.

if possible please provide me with some reference..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen SoftKeyboard sample?

there is a key in it that hides the keyboard:

```
        <Key android:codes="-3" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_done" 
            android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
```